# Append/concatenate Numpy array to Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have two np arrays, one is 1 dimensional, and the other it between 0 and 8 dimensional.  I'm trying to append the multidimensional array onto the other array, as you would with a list.  I've tried `np.append(1dim, multidim)` and `np.concatenate([1dim, multidim])` but neither have worked.

```
[-33.752, 150.902, 38.022, 203.0, 1.0]

[[ -33.75   150.9     39.805    0.       1.   ]
 [ -33.75   150.902   44.697    1.       1.   ]
 [ -33.75   150.905   49.054    2.       1.   ]
 [ -33.752  150.905   39.062  204.       1.   ]
 [ -33.755  150.905   40.698  406.       1.   ]
 [ -33.755  150.902   37.512  405.       1.   ]
 [ -33.755  150.9     36.249  404.       1.   ]
 [ -33.752  150.9     36.627  202.       1.   ]]
```

to become:

```
[-33.752, 150.902, 38.022, 203.0, 1.0],
 [ -33.75   150.9     39.805    0.       1.   ]
 [ -33.75   150.902   44.697    1.       1.   ]
 [ -33.75   150.905   49.054    2.       1.   ]
 [ -33.752  150.905   39.062  204.       1.   ]
 [ -33.755  150.905   40.698  406.       1.   ]
 [ -33.755  150.902   37.512  405.       1.   ]
 [ -33.755  150.9     36.249  404.       1.   ]
 [ -33.752  150.9     36.627  202.       1.   ]]
```

I would like to be able to reference the multidim array by using `1dim[1]`

Comment: Use a pure-Python tuple `(_1d_array, mul_dim_array)` for that...

Comment: Will the be any significant increase in runtime over large datasets by using a tuple vs np array?

Comment: With mixed sizes like there's no point making an array of arrays.  Use `concatenate` if you want to join a (5,) array with a (8,5) one to produce a (9,5) array.  But if the goal is a 2 element 'array', stick with a list.

Comment: Yeah if you say 8-dimensional I thought you mean an array of shape M×N×P×Q×R×S×T×U 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example output shows a (1x8) array concatenated with an (Nx8) array to form an (N+1 x 8) array.

If you want to create a "thing" where the first element is the 1-D array and the second element is the N-D array, a list or tuple is your bet. Numpy doesn't really have a great facility for this.

If you want to create an array that is the combination of the two 2D, based on your example, `np.vstack([flat_array, big_array])` will do that.

By the way, when describing the number of dimensions something has, array.ndim is the same as len(array.shape). Note that an array with 5 rows and 8 columns is two dimensional in the context of numpy.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [numpy.append](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) or [numpy.concatenate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html). But careful about the shape of your array. For your case you have to define the correct shape

ans=np.append([[small array]],[big array], axis=0) (Note that the extra [] is for correct shape, read the numpy.append tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it manually for any shape

```
blank= [ ] #create a blank list
a=1D array
blank.append(a)
b=nD array
for i in range(len(b)):
     blank.append(b[i])
answer=np.array(blank)
```